# Trumbowyg is not a function | Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, laravel, trumbowyg

I am working with the laravel framework and trumbowyg (javascript rich text editor, see: https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/). I am building a page where the user can edit his post and save it immediatly after he change something.

To achieve my goal that the user must not reload the page I am using AJAX to save the changes, but I am getting the error "trumbowyg is not a function" each time I click on my save button.

This is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#save', function(){
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/user/documents/{{$document->id}}/edit',
            data: {
                'created_post': $('#editor').trumbowyg('html'),
            },
            success: function(response){ 
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    })


})
```

Is there anything I can do to fix this error?

The normal function: `$('#editor').trumbowyg('html', '{!! $document->old_version !!}');` is working fine so the order of loading the javascript files should be correct, but the kind of this error speeks against this.

Comment: This works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/srtkvcfn/ (if you check the XHR in the console, you'll find the parameters contain the HTML content of the editor)

Comment: I am getting the error: "edit:345 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).trumbowyg is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (edit:345)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)"

Comment: We can't debug this without access to your live code as far as I can see. How and where are you including the `<script>`s?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not give you live access to the code. 
The scripts are loaded in the header of my document, my code above is at the end of my document. As I said above, the trumbowyg functions works outside of my document.ready function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was adding `$.noConflict();` to the first line after the definition of the function inside of the document ready call.